# Python multiprocessing shared Array on Linux memory issue

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, shared

My problem is that I am not able to allocate more than 120 millions long shared array under Linux. Under windows I do not have this issue.

Here is my example code. Everything works correctly in this code both under Linux and Windows.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Array

i1     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('1')

i2     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('2')

i3     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('3')

result =  np.frombuffer(i1.get_obj())  + np.frombuffer(i2.get_obj())  + \
          + np.frombuffer(i3.get_obj())

np.save('result', result)
print('end')
```

The next code sample, where I allocate 40M of doubles more, works perfectly on windows, but does not work under Linux for me. Iam running it in computer center, so it cannot be caused by lack of memory.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Array

i1     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('1')

i2     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('2')

i3     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('3')

i4     = Array('d', np.ones(40000000))
print('4')

result =  np.frombuffer(i1.get_obj())  + np.frombuffer(i2.get_obj())  + \
          + np.frombuffer(i3.get_obj()) + np.frombuffer(i4.get_obj()) 

np.save('result', result)
print('end')
```

The question is, does anybody know where is the problem ? And how can it be resolved ?

Comment: can you share the error you see? It could be an out of memory problem, as your linux user might have memory limits, especially on a shared computer. Try `ulimit -m`